# I'm stumped - setting the value of a form field but it's not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a form with 3 text inputs to edit records from a table. The values for the 3 fields for all records are stored in javascript arrays. I have a SELECT that displays the name field for all the records in the table. When I select an OPTION, javascript populates the 3 form field "values" with that record's values, for the user to edit.The 3 INPUTs are contained in identical DIV containers, and the attributes of the 3 INPUTs are identical (other than ids and names).

After the javascript runs, the first field would display its assigned value, but the other two continued to display their placeholders. I can watch the values change in the DOM in the developer tools as I make selections, but nothing shows in the form fields.  I am assuming my code is populating the INPUT values because the DOM is changing as expected.

I tried changing the order of the fields in the form, and now all 3 fields are failing to display their value, while the DOM still shows the elements with the values. Putting the field order back to how it was did not help.

The behavior is the same in Chrome and FireFox.

```
      document.getElementById("accountname").innerHTML         = selectedname
  document.getElementById("accountdescription").innerHTML  = jdescriptions[jnames.indexOf(selectedname)]
  document.getElementById("accountcode").innerHTML         = jcodes[jnames.indexOf(selectedname)]
```

[This screendump image shows how the FORM and the DOM are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q5cI.jpg)

Frankly I'm stumped. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: need more code sample to help you out !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set the value attribute of the input element, you cannot use innerHTML because we don't write anything between input tag. 
Since you are setting the innerHTML of input tag, your screenshot is displaying **ANOTHER ACCOUNT** between `<input></input>` but this is not the value which will be displayed for the input element.
The property innerHTML is used for elements like Div.

```
document.getElementById("accountname").value = selectedname;
```

Comment: Thanks Deep, I just realised that myself. It's all working now. What a time-waster that was.

Comment: your Welcome @Nikkorian, it happen sometimes

Answer (score 0):

It's me, of course! I should be assigning the values to .value, not .innerHTML.
All sorted.